Getting an error when passing a variable using cdktf diff command
I am declaring a variable in Terraform CDK code and using it's value to lookup a map. But, when I am running cdktf diff and passing the variable with --var myVar=myValue flag, I'm getting an error because the map is looking up with the token value rather than with myValue. How to fix this error?
Edit:
My code:
   export class MyStack extends TerraformStack {
    
      public hostingType: HostingType;
    
      public deploymentEnvironment: DeploymentEnvironment;
    
      public accountConfiguration: IAccountConfiguration;
    
      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    
        super(scope, id);
    
        this._readVariables();
    
        this._configureVariables();
    
      }
    
     
    
      private _readVariables() {
    
        // Declare variables passed through cdktf commands
    
        const hostingTypeVariable = new TerraformVariable(this, "hostingType", {
    
          type: "string",
    
          default: "normal",
    
          description:
    
            'Hosting Type variable. Valid value is one of: "normal", "special"',
    
        });
    
        this.hostingType = Fn.lookup(
    
          hostingTypeVariable.value,
    
          "hostingType",
    
          hostingTypeVariable.default,
    
        );
    
     
    
        const deploymentEnvironmentVariable = new TerraformVariable(
    
          this,
    
          "environment",
    
          {
    
            type: "string",
    
            default: "qa",
    
            description:
    
              'The "environment" variable must be specified. Valid value is one of: "qa", "prod"',
    
          },
    
        );
    
        this.deploymentEnvironment = Fn.lookup(
    
          deploymentEnvironmentVariable.value,
    
          "environment",
    
          deploymentEnvironmentVariable.default,
    
        );
    
      }
    
     
    
      private _configureVariables() {
    
        const hostingTypeConfiguration =
    
          configurationMap.hostingTypes[this.hostingType];
    
        if (!hostingTypeConfiguration) {
    
          throw new Error(
    
            `Could not find hosting type configuration for hosting type: ${this.hostingType}.  Valid value is one of: "normal", "special"'`,
    
          );
    
        } else {
    
          this.accountConfiguration =
    
            hostingTypeConfiguration[this.deploymentEnvironment];
    
        }
    
      }
}

The error I'm getting [ERROR] default - Error: Could not find hosting type configuration for hosting type: ${TfToken[TOKEN.0]}. Valid value is one of: "normal", "special"'
The command I'm running cdktf diff --var='hostingType=normal' --var='environment=qa' my-stack

Could you please share your code?

@froblesmartin done!
